# React native ticker like non stop animation of images

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I want to have ticker like non stop animation without any gap from right to left in my app i could not get such animation after trying too much, kindly anyone guide me what is the problem in my code
I tried to get ticker like non stop animation but could not get such animation

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

useEffect(() => {
    if (activeViewIndex === 1) {
      const animation = Animated.loop(
        Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
          toValue: 2,
          duration: animationDuration,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        })
      );
      animation.start();
    } else {
      animatedValue.stopAnimation();
      animatedValue.setValue(0);
    }
  }, [activeViewIndex, animatedValue]);
<Animated.View
              style={[
                styles.animationContainer,
                {
                  transform: [
                    {
                      translateX: animatedValue.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                        outputRange: [windowWidth, -windowWidth],
                      }),
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ]}
            >
              {images.map((image) => (
                <ImageContainer source={image} />
              ))}
            </Animated.View>
```